# how to subtract and get the difference of two arrays in swift 3?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3

Here i need to get the difference of both these arrays and need to save it in a separate array like `60 - 50 = 10` and one value having 'and above' in `dollarRemovedArray` can be skipped at same index in both arrays can anyone help me how to get difference of these arrays ?

```
var dollarRemovedArr = [50, 30, 0, 20, 90, 40, 80, 70, 10, 60]
var dollarRemovedArray = [Optional("60"), Optional("40"), Optional("10"), Optional("30"), Optional("and above"), Optional("50"), Optional("90"), Optional("80"), Optional("20"), Optional("70")]
```

Comment: what do you mean by `one value having 'and above' in dollarRemovedArray can be skipped ` ?

Comment: that value i will set manually as 90+ so i need to skip that  @Lion

Comment: still not clear! do you want to just substraction like `dollarRemovedArray - dollarRemovedArr` ?

Comment: that means excluding that index in both arrays so i mentioned that @Lion

Comment: which index but ?

Comment: i need to get difference of arrays like 60-50 = 10 and soon in an array  @Lion

Comment: subtracting `dollarRemovedArray - dollarRemovedArr` and getting difference of numbers in two arrays @Lion

Comment: index 4 should not calculate the difference @Lion

Comment: Okay! you need to enter 90 manually for index 4 Right ?

Comment: yes u r right @Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code

```
var outputArray = [Int]()

for var index in (0 ..< dollarRemovedArr.count) {
    guard let  dollarRemovedArrayString =  dollarRemovedArray[index] as? String,let dollarRemovedArrayItem = Int(dollarRemovedArrayString),   dollarRemovedArr.count > index  else {
        continue
    }
    outputArray.append(dollarRemovedArrayItem - dollarRemovedArr[index])

}
print(outputArray)
```

Output

> [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]

Answer (score 0):

This will Help you:

```
var dollarRemovedArr = [50, 30, 0, 20, 90, 40, 80, 70, 10, 60]
    var dollarRemovedArray = [Optional("60"), Optional("40"), Optional("10"), Optional("30"), Optional("and above"), Optional("50"), Optional("90"), Optional("80"), Optional("20"), Optional("70")]

    var resulTArray = [Int]()
    var index = 0
    for value1 in dollarRemovedArr {

        if dollarRemovedArray.count < index {
            // checking if dollarRemovedArray count less then dollarRemovedArr then adding value as default result
            resulTArray.append(value1)
            index += 1
        } else if let value2 = Int("\(dollarRemovedArray[index] ?? "")") {
            // checking if dollarRemovedArray value is in int
            resulTArray.append(value2 - value1)
            index += 1
        } else {
            // else adding default value as result
            resulTArray.append(value1)
            index += 1
        }
    }
    print(resulTArray)
```

result will be:
[10, 10, 10, 10, 90, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]